# Ubuntu 20.04.4 LTS automatic reboot

Tags: dual-boot, reboot

I have installed ubuntu (Ubuntu 20.04.4 LTS) in dual boot configuration along with windows 11 on my new machine. The configuration of the machine are as follows

a.Total hard disk : 512GB SSD

b. RAM: 16GB

c. Machine make and model: HP Gaming laptop (EC2008AX).

d. Graphics card: NVIDIA 4GB

e. enter image description hereThe winodws os was installed by default in the machine. I created an unallocated space of around 252GB on which I installed ubuntu using the USB stick. The installation method followed was to install ubuntu automatically wherein it detects the unallocated space and installs ubuntu on that space

Issue:

1. Whenever I am using google chrome or Mozilla firefox browser, the machine reboots automatically. I am not sure if that will happen while doing other tasks as well since
   I am just setting up the machine and haven't really used it for long. while booting the machine ( after selecting the os menu, some error logs appear. I have attached those images here with the question.
   [Error - Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wd1MV.jpg)
   [error image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6fxF6.jpg)

Things tried:

1. tried reinstalling chrome and updating it but it did not help. The issue occurs so suddenly that there is no scope to save unsaved work. The issue occurs on
   google chrome as well as Mozilla
2. Adjusted the value of swappiness to zero but that also did not prevent the issue.

This is the link to the file that contains logs from the Syslog
file
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1c0qlt3ZTFMhxNElWxAcDo551S4hqtYh5/view?usp=share_link

Please help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: the image of errors you showed is normal and has nothing to do with the issue. Can you check `/var/log/syslog` during the time when the reboot happened for logs regarding the issue?

Comment: Hi Esther. Thanks for the reply. I am attaching a file that contains logs from the Syslog file. The timestamp of the log is somewhere to close to the time when issue happened

Comment: @Esther: Please check the syslogs I have attached with the edited question. attaching the link here as well. Thanks  https://drive.google.com/file/d/1c0qlt3ZTFMhxNElWxAcDo551S4hqtYh5/view?usp=share_link

Comment: This is resolved after updating the packages using the apt-get update and upgrade command. Not sure what was the issue though